Is it possible to count all the possible ways to arrange these blocks in this IG game?
I have smart game iq six pro and I wonder if any formula exists to count every possible arrangement or any way to count them?
sorry for my English

No images, please,  type it out, and also edit in what you have tried so far even if unfruitful

What is the meaning of "IG" ?

Using Google Lens I have found this video explaining the game, which is the minimum for being able to answer to the question : https://www.youtube.com/shorts/MlArDOiGVKI?app=desktop

These pieces (akin to classical "pentaminos") have a name : "pentahexes". See here and there.

I don't think there's a "formula", per se, for the arrangements, but one could perform a computer-assisted search.

@JeanMarie They're mostly pentahexes, but there are some tetrahexes in there too.

@Jaap Scherphuis Thanks. I hadn't noticed... This makes the task even more difficult... The answer that can be done is that a formula is probably out of reach...

I don't think there is any way to do this other than an exhaustive search, and it is large enough that a computer search is the only practical way.
I used my own software to do this (Polyform Solver), and after about four and a half minutes it had completed  its search, finding 59494 solutions.


I am baffled !...
